# Which player scored the most points in one game in each season?

Tags: basketball, trivia, statistics, nba

I would like to see a statistic showing which player has scored the most points in one basketball game every season. I know Wilt Chamberlain holds the general record, but it would be nice to see who came close and who had the best scoring game in each season.

Comment: http://www.basketball-reference.com/ probably has the info you're looking for.

Comment: This wouldn't be too difficult to do via Wax's link... but it's a matter of either someone else doing repetitive/dull lookups for each season, or you :P

Comment: Are you [Peter Noble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Noble), the former British football player? (It would be a nice coincidence to have the same person here as a user and mentioned in one of the answers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the [**1963-1964** season](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player_id=&match=game&year_min=&year_max=&age_min=0&age_max=99&team_id=&opp_id=&is_playoffs=N&round_is_eds=Y&round_is_edf=Y&round_is_ec1=Y&round_is_ecs=Y&round_is_ecf=Y&round_is_wds=Y&round_is_wdf=Y&round_is_wc1=Y&round_is_wcs=Y&round_is_wcf=Y&round_is_fin=Y&game_num_type=&game_num_min=&game_num_max=&game_month=&game_location=&game_result=&is_starter=&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=gt&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=gt&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=gt&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=gt&c4val=&order_by=pts) as of the **2016-2017** NBA season:

- **2018-2019:** James Harden (61 - 01/23/2019, 03/22/2019)
- **2017-2018:** James Harden (60 - 01/30/2018)
- **2016-2017:** Devin Booker (70 - 03/24/2017)
- **2015-2016:** Kobe Bryant (60 - 04/13/2016)
- **2014-2015:** Kyrie Irving (57 - 03/12/2015)
- **2013-2014:** Carmelo Anthony (62 - 01/24/2014)
- **2012-2013:** Stephen Curry (54 - 02/27/2013)
- **2011-2012:** Deron Williams (57 - 03/04/2012)
- **2010-2011:** LeBron James (51 - 02/03/2011)
- **2009-2010:** Brandon Jennings (55 - 11/14/2009)
- **2008-2009:** Kobe Bryant (61 - 02/02/2009)
- **2007-2008:** Kobe Bryant (53 - 03/28/2008)
- **2006-2007:** Kobe Bryant (65 - 03/16/2007)
- **2005-2006:** Kobe Bryant (81 - 01/22/2006)
- **2004-2005:** Allen Iverson (60 - 02/12/2005)
- **2003-2004:** Tracy McGrady (62 - 03/10/2004)
- **2002-2003:** Kobe Bryant (55 - 03/28/2003)
- **2001-2002:** Allen Iverson (58 - 01/15/2002)
- **2000-2001:** Jerry Stackhouse (57 - 04/03/2001)
- **1999-2000:** Shaquille O'Neal (61 - 03/06/2000)
- **1998-1999:** Grant Hill (46 - 02/08/1999), Allen Iverson (46 - 02/12/1999), Antonio McDyess (46 - 02/28/1999)
- **1997-1998:** Karl Malone (56 - 04/07/1998)
- **1996-1997**: Michael Jordan (51 - 01/21/1997)
- **1995-1996:** Michael Jordan (53 - 03/07/1996)
- **1994-1995:** Glen Rice (56 - 04/15/1995)
- **1993-1994:** David Robinson (71 - 04/24/1994)
- **1992-1993:** Michael Jordan (64 - 01/16/1993)
- **1991-1992:** Dominique Wilkins (52 - 12/07/1991)
- **1990-1991:** Michael Adams (54 - 03/23/1991)
- **1989-1990:** Michael Jordan (69 - 03/28/1990)
- **1988-1989:** Michael Jordan (53 - 01/21/1989)
- **1987-1988:** Michael Jordan (59 - 04/03/1988)
- **1986-1987:** Michael Jordan (61 - 03/04/1987, 04/16/1987)
- **1985-1986:** Dominique Wilkins (57 - 04/10/1986)
- **1984-1985:** Bernard King (60 - 12/25/1984), Larry Bird (60 - 03/12/1985)
- **1983-1984:** Purvis Short (57 - 01/07/1984)
- **1982-1983:** Adrian Dantley (57 - 12/04/1982)
- **1981-1982:** Moses Malone (53 - 02/02/1982), Adrian Dantley (53 - 04/10/1982)
- **1980-1981:** Adrian Dantley (55 - 02/06/1981)
- **1979-1980:** George Gervin (55 - 01/23/1980)
- **1978-1979:** George Gervin (52 - 01/11/1979)
- **1977-1978:** David Thompson (73 - 04/09/1978)
- **1976-1977:** Pete Maravich (68 - 02/25/1977)
- **1975-1976:** Bob McAdoo (52 - 03/17/1976)
- **1974-1975:** Rick Barry (55 - 01/23/1975)
- **1973-1974:** Rick Barry (64 - 03/26/1974)
- **1972-1973:** Phil Chenier (53 - 12/06/1972)
- **1971-1972:** Chet Walker (56 - 02/06/1972)
- **1970-1971:** Kareem Abdul-Jabbar (53 - 11/04/1970)
- **1969-1970:** Lou Hudson (57 - 11/10/1969)
- **1968-1969:** Wilt Chamberlain (66 - 02/09/1969)
- **1967-1968:** Wilt Chamberlain (68 - 12/16/1967)
- **1966-1967:** Wilt Chamberlain (58 - 02/13/1967)
- **1965-1966:** Wilt Chamberlain (65 - 02/07/1966)
- **1964-1965:** Wilt Chamberlain (63 - 11/26/1964)
- **1963-1964:** Wilt Chamberlain (59 - 12/06/1963, 01/28/1964, 02/11/1964)

Comment: We should probably aim to update this no more than once per year.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Agreed...and since the season is not yet over, it makes little sense to update this answer before the end of the season (which is in roughly two weeks - last season, Kobe Bryant scored 60 in the last game of the season). Thanks for the edit, Deez.